# How to: prevent accidental closing of Eclipse Ant view OR make view remember contents on reopening?

Tags: eclipse, ant

I use a lot of projects and ant buildfiles in Eclipse, and every now and then I close the Ant view tab by accident. After I reopen the view, I have to add the previous content (dozens of buildfiles) again manually, which is kinda uncomfortable.

I'd guess the right way to avoid this situation would be:

1. Some option to prevent the accidental closing of views, like marking them fixed in a perspective, getting a confirmation dialog when clicking the close button etc. I guess this would be a nice feature, but didn't find anything like this, but still if there exists one such feature in Eclipse, please tell me how to find it.
2. A feature specifically for the ant view, so it can remember it's contents after closing / reopening. This also seems to be a nice feature, but so far looks nonexistent. If you know about such a feature, please give me some directions.
3. Some other solution I can't even guess...

The above options pretty much look like feature requests, which should be sent towards the Eclipse dev. team, but I still hold some hope that these features already exist and I just failed to find them.